# Connect B2C inside AAD Enterprise Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are trying to complete SSO inside Azure Active Directory to Azure B2C. We are trying to use AAD Enterprise Application SAML provider to connect Azure B2C.

I don't find any article related this. We don't need SSO from B2C to AAD. We need only SSO  from AAD to B2C.

Please provide any URL or any link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAD is designed to be the main IDP. You can federate in but not out.

Also, as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-idp-initiated-flow),

"We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, such as Active Directory Federation Services or Salesforce. IdP-initiated flow is supported only for local account authentication in Azure AD B2C".